# Using Entity Framework with an SSAS Cube

Tags: entity-framework, ssas

Is it possible to use Entity Framework (any version, including, and preferably 4.0) to query an SSAS cube (preferably SSAS 2008)?

Comment: Try https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/860143/Introduction-to-Percolator-Analysis-Services-LINQ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say no. There's a few questions on here looking for that, asking for the ORM equivalent for SSAS and such. LINQ to MDX would be lovely, but so far as is known it's just not on the cards.

I've been looking and pondering for years for something simple in code to get data back to the middle tier, but I've never found it. Things like AdomdDataReader and CellSet are OK, but require hand-written MDX, there's no easy way around it.

Sorry for the bad news, if anyone can prove me wrong I'd be overjoyed :/

Comment: All the research I've done has pointed me in the same direction. There isn't support for this, and it seems to be due to the complex nature of MDX. I've seen a couple of items with "nice to haves" as other frameworks folks are writing, but nothing concrete.

Comment: Chris Webb has some nice ideas on how to do it but nothing as yet.
http://cwebbbi.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7B84B0F2C239489A!1956.entry