# Is LINQ to MDX (Entity Framework) available for writing OLAP Query?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, mdx

I was ended up on writing nested queries against the data source using LINQ TO SQL. But now everything is moved to OLAP Cube and I need to get the same result from MDX Queries. Translation of those LINQ based queries to MDX Query is quite difficult.

Is there Entity framework available TO OLAP ? If so, from where can I include that altogether in my application?

I need to some examples to see regarding this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Entity Framework with an SSAS Cube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233839/using-entity-framework-with-an-ssas-cube)

Comment: I have read that.
But it has been asked 5 years ago. I don't know If Microsoft has developed something new in this regard

Comment: " is quite difficult." ... I suspect this is an understatement.