# Reverse engineer a cube(Analysis Service) enabling data access for .NET applications?

Tags: sql, linq, mdx, cube, analysisservices

how to reverse engineer an SQL cube(Analysis Service)so that a data access for .NET applications is enabled , just like Entity Framework (ex. dataBase first approach ) but instead of an SQL DB a live Cube(Multidimensional Expressions) that can be queried via LINQ query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a data provider such as [ADOMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/adomd-net/developing-with-adomd-net?view=sql-server-2017) which can connect to a cube to read its structure, and run MDX queries to return tables of values.

Comment: yes great used that and worked , but is there a tool that is LINQ query enabled as ADOMD only allows mdx query , and would it be a live cube ?

Comment: If LINQ is for OLTP databases only (?) then I guess OLAP cubes are not possible.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233839/using-entity-framework-with-an-ssas-cube